# No entry in log_quote table

Tags: magento

In our website there is no entry in log_quote table. When every we try to make checkout/order the entry does not create. Can anyone know why this happens and how to solve this.

We are using Magento EE 1.10.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrongly comment a code, this stop the enter in log_quote table.

I un-comment that code, now its working.